# Blender ignores switching from "Material" to "Vertex color" in grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

1. I can start a fresh file.
2. Make a black stroke with with GP
3. Swtich to Vertex Color (picking any color)
4. Stroke is still black

Answer (score 1):

Figure it out, didn't realize vertex colors in GP aren't visible in "Solid" viewport shading.